# "operation is not allowed when the object is open"

Tags: ms-access, vb6

When I am trying to execute the program I am getting an error like "operation is not allowed when the object is open". I'm using vb 6.0 and microsoft access database. here is the source code

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
        dtaOverhead.Recordset.Open "Delete from variable where SWACTFM= " & txtEntry(0).Text & " And SWBUDACT = " & txtEntry(1).Text & " And SWREMFM = '" & txtEntry(12).Text & "' And SWACTRAW = " & txtEntry(2).Text & " And SWBUDRAW = " & txtEntry(3).Text & " And SWREMRAW = '" & txtEntry(13).Text & "' And SWACTWHS = " & txtEntry(4).Text & " And SWBUDWHS = " & txtEntry(5).Text & " And SWREMWHS = '" & txtEntry(14).Text & "' And SWACTLAB = " & txtEntry(6).Text & " And SWBUDLAB = " & txtEntry(7).Text & " And SWREMLAB = '" & txtEntry(15).Text & "' And SWACTWORK = " & txtEntry(8).Text & " And SWBUDWORK = " & txtEntry(9).Text & " And SWREMWORK = '" & txtEntry(16).Text & "' And SWACTTOTAL = " & txtEntry(10).Text & " And SWBUDTOTAL = " & txtEntry(11).Text & " And SWREMTOTAL = '" & txtEntry(17).Text & "'"
        MsgBox "Record deleted successfully !", vbInformation, "Deletion Successful"
        Call Filllist
        Call clearall
        cmdSave.Caption = "&Save"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please always format your code using the `{}` button. Which line fails? You are calling two procedures, if the code fails in one of them, post the code for that procedure. You can set breakpoints with F9. Use F8 to step through your code and find the failing line.

Comment: sorry, can you explain me details about that

Comment: I thought I had. Which part did you not understand?

Comment: That is quite messy looking code, could you explain more as to what you want it to achieve step by step please?

Comment: If think the `dtaOverhead.Recordset.Open` part fails since we don't know what's in the Filllist and Clearall procedures.

Answer (score 4):

You can't open a Recordset twice (er, without closing it in between anyway).

A `DELETE` would normally be done using `Connection.Execute` or `Command.Execute`, not `Recordset.Open`.

Comment: I think dtaOverhead is a DAO control. You are referring to ADO. But you are right about closing the recordset before executing the next query.

Comment: Scary thought, but then so is doing something like a DELETE by using the Recordset of a data control whether ADO or DAO.